# Visual Studio __asm Error with assume

Tags: c++, visual-studio, assembly

I am programming something in Visual Studio (C++) and have the following code in one of my functions:

```
__asm
    {
        ASSUME FS : NOTHING

        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR FS : [18]
        MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS : [EAX + 30]
        MOVZX EAX, BYTE PTR DS : [EAX + 2]
        RET
    }
```

When i try it to compile, Visual Studio gives me the Error Code C2400 "Inlineassembler: Syntaxerror in "Opcode"; "FS" not found" (I have the German version installed, so i don't know what the exact message would be in english.)
My Program is x86 on x64 compiled.

I hope anyone can help me. Thanks

Comment: Try removing the `ASSUME FS: NOTHING`. I don't believe it is useful in this situation.with inline assembly

Comment: Another option would be to use the built in [__readfsdword](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3887zk1s.aspx) and skip the assembly code.